# C++ function in parent return child

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child, setter, mutators

I would like to have the mutators (setters) in my class to return `this` to allow for jQuery-like `a.name("something").address("somethingelse");`
I have a parent class (`Entity`) and several childclasses (`Client, Agent etc.`). The mutators for most things are inherited from the `Entity` class (like name or address), but they return an `Entity` object, so I can't call Client mutators on them.

In other words:

```
// name mutator
Entity& Entity::name( const string& name ) {
    // [...] checks
    _name = name;
    return *this;
}

// budgetRange mutator
Client& Client::budgetRange( const long int& range ) {
    // [...] checks
    _budgetRange = range;
    return *this;   
}
```

then when I call it:

```
Client a; a.name("UserName123").budgetRange(50);
```

The compiler (logically) says, that the Entity object has no budgetRange member (because name returns an Entity, not a Client).

My question now is: how could I implement something like this? I thought about overloading all the Entity functions in the childclasses but that wouldn't be nice and would be against the idea of inheritance :)

Thank you in advance for your ideas :D

Comment: google also for `method chaining` and `named parameter idiom`, which is what you are doing. Note that, when inheriting from `Client` your code will break again using CRTP solution below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template<class Derived>
class Entity
{
    Derived* This() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }

public:
    Derived& name(const string& name)
    {
        ...
        return *This();
    }
};

class Client : public Entity<Client>
{
public:
    Client& budgetRange(const long& range)
    {
        ...    
        return *this;   
    }
};
```

If you want to use virtual functions, you can also add abstract base class, like this:

```
class AbstractEntity
{
public:
     virtual void foo() = 0;

     virtual ~AbstractEntity();
};

template<class Derived>
class Entity : AbstractEntity
{...};
```

Comment: I really like this idea (especially the This() function ^^).
Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Excellent stuff. I've been searching for a good example of CRTP. Thanks.

Comment: @sje397 another good example of CRTP is a generic tree class, that provides concrete node implementations via `template<class D> class node`. For example: `D &node::left()` can provide the concrete node impl. That way you can stuff all the tree logic into the generic node class.

Comment: Note though that your classes no longer have a polymorphic base class now. They're entirely independent of one another. You've got one distinct base class per derived class now.

Comment: Should you not `class Client : _public_ Entity<Client>`?

Comment: @phresnel, I'd like all of them to be `struct`s, but a lot of people like to write `class` and `public` keywords

Answer (score 3):

The "curiously recursive template" pattern could help here; make the base class a template, parametrised by the derived class, along the lines of:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct Entity {
    Derived & name(std::string const & name) {
        // stuff
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
};

struct Client : Entity<Client> {
    Client & budget(long range) {
        // stuff
        return *this;
    }
};

Client().name("Mike").budget(50); // should compile
```

This will only work if all your types inherit directly from `Entity`. If you need the types to be polymorphic (i.e. all share a common base class), then you'll need to add another non-template base class, and have `Entity` inherit from that.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, but I'll choose Abyx' one as he included the this() idea :) 
Upvoted though.

Answer (score 3):

Now that nearly everything has already been said, I want to add a piece of answer that allows one to use the CRTP over multiple levels of inheritance:

The above CRTP implementations break when one wants to inherit from `Client`, since `Derived`  will refer to `Client`. In case you want to be able to carry the named parameter idiom over multiple levels of inheritance using CRTP pattern, you need to code your classes like so

```
template<class Derived>
class Entity_T
{
protected:
    Derived* This() { return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
public:
    Derived& name(const string& name)
    {
        ...
        return *This();
    }
};

template<class Derived>
class Client_T : public Entity_T<Derived>
{
    Derived& budgetRange(const long& range)
    {
        ...    
        return *This();   
    }
};
```

To provide the user a template-free version of `Client_T` add

```
class Client : public Client_T<Client> {};
```

Whether or not this is worth the enlarged code base is entirely up to you. Note, that I haven't compiled the code above.